# ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects in 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am attempting to compare a column in 2 different data frames and getting an error.  My goal is to determine if the playerID in df1 matches the playerID in df2. Also not sure if it makes a difference but the data in each data frame is of different lengths.

Here is my code with examples of the data frames:

```
cleaned_hof_df = hof_df[(hof_df.inducted == 'Y') & (hof_df.category == 'Player')] 
cleaned_hof_df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

cleaned_hof_df.head(3)

cleaned_wins_losses_df = pitching_df[(pitching_df.W > 0) & (pitching_df.L > 0)] 
cleaned_wins_losses_df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

cleaned_wins_losses_df.head(3)

cleaned_hof_df.playerID == cleaned_wins_losses_df.playerID
```

[image: Here is my code with examples of the data frames]

Comment: You should work to create an example that reproduces the error and type the code directly into a question, rather posting screenshots of code. There is a good [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3639023) of the reasoning behind that.

Comment: That makes sense.  I am a new at this but should have figured that one out on my own.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data frames

```
cleaned_hot_df
```

and

```
cleaned_win_losses_df
```

have different number of rows, so the corresponding series

```
cleaned_hot_df.playerID
```

and

```
cleaned_win_losses_df.playerID
```

have different lengths.

So your two series are not identically-labeled (which is the error you got).

Comment: So, I can't compare two series that are not identical length.  I need to find another solution.  I will start searching.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You may use `cleaned_win_losses_df[cleaned_win_losses_df.playerID.isin(cleaned_hot_df.playerID)]`.